# how i can create card list via card class and List class in Flutter?

Tags: list, flutter, flutter-layout

This time , extraordinary there is no problem about code. I just couldn't find a way how i can make it.

First , what i want to do ?

i want make a card list what created automatically which take data from a List. in my mind , it has 2 part. One of them is i have a card template what has been made from Card Class. Its like that :

```html
class MissionCard extends StatelessWidget {
  MissionCard({ @required this.cardOwner, @required this.missionName1, @required this.color,@required this.missionName2 });
  final String cardOwner;
  final String missionName1;
  final String missionName2;
  final Color color;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 300,
      height: 105,
      child: Card(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
        color: color,
        elevation: 10,
        
        
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            
            children: <Widget>[
              Image.asset(cardOwner.toString(), height: 60,width: 60,fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,),
              Image.asset(missionName1.toString(), height: 60,width: 60,fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,),
              Image.asset(missionName2.toString(), height: 60,width: 60,fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,),
              Image.asset("assets/assetsname", height: 60,width: 60,fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,),
              
            ],
          ),
        )
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

i can make a card if i will fill this datas manually as you understand.

`final String cardOwner;
  final String missionName1;
  final String missionName2;`

But i want that this data will be added from a list automatically. This is example data List.

```html
List
<MissionListTemplate> cardData = 

[ MissionListTemplate( 

missionOwner: "assets/owner.png", 
missionName1: "assets/mission1.png", 
missionName2: "assets/mission2.png" ), 

MissionListTemplate( 

missionOwner: "assets/owner.png", 
missionName1: "assets/mission1.png", 
missionName2: "assets/mission2.png"
  ) ];
```

I want the data of the cards to be created automatically by filling in automatically from MissionListTamplate. Its kind of like that : i have very different cakes ( datas in List ) and i want put in them in same box ( MissionCard ) automatically.
and when they fiil, all cards should be in stack in Column. For example , My codes should create 2 different cards from this List.

Second : whats wrong ?

i don't know how i can make this . it's kind of automation and i stack in my mind . i need a solution. If i couldnt tell to case , i can draw logic schematics. Sorry for take your time, i hope you can help me and tell how i can figure it out!!!

Comment: Are you using your MissionCards in a ListView-Widget or something to build your List? Can we see the code?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. As a result of a long study, I managed to solve it with the following guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got a `MissionListTemplate` object, you can presumably (based on usual conventions) create a `MissionCard` from it like:

```
MissionCard(cardOwner: MissionListTemplate.missionOwner, missionName1: MissionListTemplate.missionName1, missionName2: MissionListTemplate.missionName2);
```

This is going to return a `Widget`.

You've got a list of `MissionListTemplate`s, so you can loop through the list and create a `MissionCard` for each item in the list. Again, a `MissionCard` is a `Widget`, so you would store all these `Widget`s in a list for future use, like so:

```
List<Widget> missionCardList = new List(); // Creating a List of Widgets

for(template in cardData){
  missionCardList.add(MissionCard(
    cardOwner: template.missionOwner, 
    missionName1: template.missionName1, 
    missionName2: template.missionName2
    )
  ); // Adding new MissionCard to the list above
}
```

Now you've got a list of `MissionCard`s with the values you want. All you need to do is put them in a `Stack`/`Column`/`Row`/etc. as per your choice. If you have a look at these Widgets, they take children as an argument instead of a single child. The children argument takes a... Yep, a list of `Widget`. This is exactly what you created above. So you can just set the children of the parent Widget as your `missionCardList` and be done with it, like below:

```
Column(
  children: missionCardList,
)
```

Comment: To be honest, I'm new to Flutter, and thanks to your help, I managed to get out of this situation that I couldn't get out of. It was also very educational. It cost me -2 :) but I learned very good things. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: We've all been there :) Happy to help. You can accept this answer if it worked for you